# Using Create-React-App: Switching through multiple pages which passes props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm currently working on a school project which I intended to do mainly with HTML/CSS and some javascript. However, our advisor told us to partially implement react, so I'm kind of in a state where I have no idea what I am doing and the due date is coming up soon.

Following is what I have as of now.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Page from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
class Page extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
                page:"categories",
                loc: "Some Location",
                category: "Resources", //This is filled by user choice
                scenario: "Emergency" //This is filled by user choice
        };
        this.shiftPage = this.shiftPage.bind(this)
    }

    shiftPage(newPage) {
        this.setState({page: newPage}); 

    }

    render(){
        if (this.state.page === "scenario"){
            return(
                <Scenario page ={this.state.page} loc={this.state.loc} category={this.state.category} scenario={this.state.scenario} shiftPage={this.shiftPage}></Scenario> 
            );
        }
        else if(this.state.page === "categories"){
            return(
                <Categories page ={this.state.page} loc={this.state.loc} category={this.state.category} scenario={this.state.scenario} shiftPage={this.shiftPage}></Categories> 
            );
        }
        else if(this.state.page === "tips"){
            return(
                <Tips page ={this.state.page} loc={this.state.loc} category={this.state.category} scenario={this.state.scenario}></Tips>
            );
        }
        else if(this.state.page === "rights"){
            return(
                <Rights page ={this.state.page} loc={this.state.loc} category={this.state.category} scenario={this.state.scenario}></Rights>
            );
        }
        else{
            alert("Page Not Found.")
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
                        <p>The requested page does not exist. Please redirect to the <a href="../../welcome.html">Welcome</a> Page</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
class Categories extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( //some html code...
        <button onClick={this.props.shiftPage("rights")}>
                    <div className = "category-box" id= "category-rights" >
                            <div className = "category-icon-container" id = "rights-container">
                                <img id = "rights-icon" src={require("./img/Laws.svg")} alt="Law Icon" height="37px" width="37px"></img>
                            </div>
                            <p>Rights</p>
                    </div>
        </button>
//Some HTML code...
```

Basically what I am trying to do is have the parent class Page to render different pages based on user choices in the previous pages. As of now I only have `this.page.state` be updated, but I intend to update other states as well.

The major problem with this code I have as of now, is that when I load the first page, I expect it to load the page `categories` as it is set initially at the Page class. However, it loads the `rights` page, although the button is not clicked yet. Is it possible to have an implementation where it goes like

1. Page renders based on `this.state.page`
2. User makes a choice
3. Update the Page State on `this.state.page` from the Child class based `onClick`
4. Page class rerenders to the new page

I am open to any and all modifications including restructuring my entire code base. Furthermore, if react implementation is not the feasible option for such task, if you could redirect to another framework to do so, that would be amazing!

Any and all help will be appericiated! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Just to follow up, there are more child classes, which I haven't posted. Each one just has a blob of HTML text, as I made the HTML pages first, and I'm changing bits and pieces inside the render() function of the children classes to do all of the above features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the use of

```
<button onClick={this.props.shiftPage("rights")}>
```

This is a function invocation, meaning the function would be called on `render`.

To correct this and call the function only on click, you would want to refractor to:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.shiftPage("rights")}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feature you want to implement is called routing. To solve this problem, you can use the react-router library. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Just wondering but is there any advantage in using routing instead of just fixing the error I had as mentioned in another solution by Boy With Silver Wings?

Comment: Yes, this is powerful library built to solve routing problems. For example working with browser history, redirecting etc.

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Switch, Route, } from 'react-router-dom';

import Scenario from '../Scenario'
import Categories from '../Categories'
import Tips from '../Tips'
import Rights from '../Rights'

const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  min-height: 100%;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
       <Helmet titleTemplate="Admin" defaultTitle="Apex Sales 
        Portal">
         <meta name="description" content="Apex Sales Portal" />
       </Helmet>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/scenario" component={Scenario} exact />
         <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} exact />
         <Route path="/tips" component={Tips} exact />
         <Route path="/rights" component={Rights} exact />
       </Switch>   
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}

index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from "../src/containers/App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
   document.getElementById("root")
);

registerServiceWorker();
```